# On-the-fly GZIP Filesize Estimates

Tags: compression, gzip

I am attempting to write a program that splits a large dataset into smaller datasets of a target size `target` or less, when GZIP compressed.

Thus far, the best I have come up with is to just track raw string length of the data I've seen so far, and estimate the final size with some GZIP compression ratio guess. This results in some pretty wildly off estimates though. Most of the time, the estimated size is within 20% of my target, but sometimes I'll get files that are 100s of % bigger than my estimate predicts.

Additionally, it seems like the compression estimates are periodic. So if I want 10MB files, I'll end up with mostly 10MB files, but then lumps at 20, 30, 40 MB in the filesize distribution.

So is there any way to make on-the-fly educated guesses as to output compressed file sizes, without actually compression the assembled stream so far? Is it possible with a different compression format? I don't need it to be perfect, but I do want it to be close.

Pseudocode example (in practice I can do this with java, python, or scala. This is just illustrative):

```
COMPRESSION_RATIO_GUESS = 20
targetSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024

with open("bigfile.txt","r") as f:
    so_far = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        so_far += len(line)
        if so_far/COMPRESSION_RATIO_GUESS > targetSize:
            # start new file, write rows so far
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found, such estimations are a terrible way to try to achieve your objective. There are better ways.

We would need to hear more about your application. What is the size of the datasets you are compressing? What sort of target sizes are you trying to get? How close do you want to get to the target size? Where can you split your dataset, and how often, in byte distance, do those occur?

I would recommend a relatively simple approach, which uses zlib's ability to flush out blocks. You would compress some portion of your dataset, and flush the output.  Save the length and where that compressed data ended. (You can flush to a byte boundary.) Repeat with another portion. Continue until you go over your target. Then back up to the last time you flushed, and finish that stream with a final block and trailer. Now start a new file with the data you just backed over.

Depending on your numbers, the amount you compress in a block can be chosen to permit you to get close to the target, and not significantly impact the compression ratio.

There are more complex approaches that allow you get as close to the target as possible, as used by [fitblk](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/fitblk.c). fitblk compresses past the target, and the decompresses that just up to the target. It then recompresses just that amount, and then decompresses and compresses a third time to get with a few bytes of filling up to the target.

Comment: I like the idea of gathering and flushing zlib blocks, I'll see what I can do with that. 

My actual use case is an attempt to get approximately deterministic output filesizes from a Spark/Scala application. I'm iterating over rows within a partition and marking them with a new repartition column which can be used to group rows into specific files when Spark is ready to write the outputs. So more or less the procedure I describe above but more complex in practice.

Comment: And since I forgot to answer your first question, I'm breaking partitions of data (a few gigabytes) into relatively small files, on the order of 10-50MB.

Comment: Good. Typical block sizes are in the KB, so you can get very close to your target. You could just feed 1 MB of compressed data at a time, and there will be almost no impact on the compression ratio due to flushing.

Comment: How do I go about figuring out the numbers here for a different application? For example, I'm aiming for output size bounded by 380KB.  Input documents are text in a programming language and is likely reasonably repetitive.  Is flushing every 64KB likely to be reasonable here? (Originally asked with slightly more details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019801/is-there-a-bound-on-the-amount-zlib-deflate-would-output-if-i-z-finished-now but then I found this duplicate myself.)

Comment: @DavidGlasser If you want an integral number of items in each block, then simply compress one at a time, ending each with a `Z_SYNC_FLUSH`. If it fits in your block, then append it, and try the next one. If it doesn't fit, then end your block with a `Z_FINISH`, and start your next block with the item that didn't fit.

Comment: Hmm, I thought using `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` on every single item would hurt my compression. (My individual uncompressed items range in size a lot (from dozens of bytes to hundreds of KB) and I expect there to be a fair amount of duplicated substrings across items.) Doesn't every `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` mean rewriting the Huffman table and such? (Or is there some trick to let me "undo" the internal state of the algorithm after deflating a block with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` so I can try again with `Z_NO_FLUSH`?)

Comment: Hundreds of K, no problem. Flushes after dozens of bytes though would hurt compression. You would still get the benefit of matching strings across the flushes, but the header for each block could itself be on the order of dozens of bytes. (The average is around 80 bytes.) So, yes, if you're down at that level, you might as well group more of those before flushing.

Comment: Er, one last question (and I'm super appreciative that you take the time to help random zlib users on StackOverflow!): it sounds like you're saying that if the last block is too big I just should pretend I never compressed it (only keeping the part up to the previous `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` and then finish with `Z_FINISH`).  But... doesn't `Z_FINISH` write a trailer, with a checksum, that will be wrong if I just ignore part of what it produced?

Comment: (Or are you suggesting that in that case we restart and recompress the whole section from the start? If so, I assume we don't actually have to reproduce the same set of `Z_SYNC_FLUSH`es as we go, because presumably skipping flushes is never going to make the output longer, right?)

Comment: You can use `deflateCopy()` to fork the deflate state at each decision point (making sure to `deflateEnd()` ones that you decide to not use). Or you can raw deflate and build your own gzip header and trailer (pretty trivial), and use `crc32_combine()` to update the CRC when you decide to keep the block.