# Is there a bound on the amount zlib deflate would output if I Z_FINISH'ed now?

Tags: zlib

I have a sequence of items.

I would like to create a sequence of gzipped buffers, each of which contains some of my items (concatenated in some way with minimal overhead).

I want to get good compression that crosses over multiple items (ie, I don't want do a Z_SYNC_FLUSH after adding each item).

I have a limit on how large each gzipped buffer can be (let's say 400KB).

I don't care how many items end up in each buffer; I'd like to get as many items in each buffer while still keeping each buffer under 400KB.

Naively, one could implement this something like this pseudocode:

```
while items is not empty:
  create a new deflate
  create a new output buffer
  while items is not empty and we have written less than ??? to the output buffer:
    remove one item from items
    call deflate() with the item, writing its output to the output buffer
    call deflate repeatedly with no more input until it has nothing less to write
  call deflate with no new data and Z_FINISH
  call deflate repeatedly with no more input until it has nothing less to write
  add the output buffer to the output sequence
```

The question is: what do I put for `???`?  Zlib may have a lot of data that it's ready to write out.  I can extract all the pending data each time it's available, but if I'm not aggressively flushing, it won't actually have pending data available most of the time. (And aggressively flushing will ruin my compression.)

Is there a bound on how much data Zlib will output when I call Z_FINISH, such that I can just set `???` to my target maximum output size (say 400KB) minus that amount?

For example, I'm aware that with its default settings, Zlib's window size is 32KB. Does that imply that when I call deflate with `Z_FINISH` in the algorithm above, it never will generate more than roughly 32KB of additional output? (And if so, what is "roughly" — for example, can I assume relatively strictly that it will never produce more than 40KB of additional output, and thus I can set the `???` to 360KB to achieve my goal of "buffers below 400KB"?)

(I'm actually using Deflater in Java but it wraps zlib; I hope the answer isn't "you can use `deflatePending` to answer your question directly, but it's not accessible in Java". My understanding is that `deflatePending` is about "how much can be read right now", not "how much would be written by a flush".)